# Is there a resource for viewing all the languages?

Tags: early-modern-english

Maybe this is the wrong website, but is there a link to see all the languages (current and past)?

Comment: Wikipedia languages

Comment: Depends on what you want to view. [Ethnologue](http://www.ethnologue.com/) for  facts about living languages.[ George Mason Accent Archive](http://accent.gmu.edu/) for native and foreign English accents, in sound and IPA transcription.  And, by the way, nothing about this has a thing to do with "Early Modern English".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for resources, and not specific to the English language.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few resources for you:

[List of languages by number of native speakers (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers)

[Languages spoken in each country (InfoPlease)](http://www.infoplease.com/ipa/A0855611.html/)

[50 Most Widely Spoken Languages in the World (Photius)](http://www.photius.com/rankings/languages2.html)

Hope this helps!

Comment: There is something odd about the first of those lists. For example it gives the number of native English speakers as 365 million. Well the USA and UK alone number that many, before you consider Canada, Australia, New Zealand, South Africa etc. And under *French* it says 72 million - not many more than the French-speaking parts of Europe alone.

Answer (score 0):

While not exhaustive, Omniglot is a great place to go for almost 200 languages. I really doubt you will find a single exhaustive resource, but Omniglot was recommended by a few of my language professors.

http://www.omniglot.com